# how to get internal function return value

Tags: javascript

I needs to call one javascription from another function like below. I needs to get the return value from the internal function. Please see below.

How can I get return value from the function getpopupbox()?

```
function first(){
     var type = getpopupbox();
     if( type == 'yes' ) 
       //Some code here
     if( type == 'no' ) 
       //Some code here 
     if( type == 'yes/no' ) 
       //Some code here 
}
function getpopupbox(){
 // I have 2 cases here
  if( case == '2' )
     return 'yes';
  if( case == '1' )
     return 'no';
  if( case == '0' )
     return 'yes/no'; 
}
```

Comment: it looks fine... what is the problem...except that `case` is a keyword so you can't use it as a variable name

Comment: where you have set Case value?

Comment: I am not getting the return value from the function 'getpopupbox()'....

Comment: what is case? where is it declared if it is a variable

Comment: I just set the case value in the getpopupbox function itself. It is dynamic value and it varying again and again.

Comment: @rize Then show us an actual working example, not this broken one.

Comment: Change `case` to another word. It's reserved.

Comment: case is a reserved keyword to be used with switch-case statements. You don't have a switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `case` as a variable name. It's a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Your script is probably crashing when it tries to parse that function, and I would imagine that if you checked your console, you would see an error there.

Comment: @rize Glad to help. You shoul use the checkmark icon to accept whichever answer you found to be the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` variable is messing up with `switch case` thing

rename your variable to another name.

Like this

```
var condCase='2';
function first(){
     var type = getpopupbox();
     if( type == 'yes' ) 
       //Some code here
     if( type == 'no' ) 
       //Some code here 
     if( type == 'yes/no' ) 
       //Some code here 
}
function getpopupbox(){
 // I have 2 cases here
  if( condCase== '2' )
     return 'yes';
  if( condCase== '1' )
     return 'no';
  if( condCase== '0' )
     return 'yes/no'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your case variable with some other name.Case is a reserved keyword in js.